# How can I set a field value in a display form when a list item is first read?

Tags: list, list-form, display-form, default-value

I have a list with multiple columns.

This list may include multiple records. I want the value of a specific field to be changed when a special record is read for the first time.

Comment: Disclaimer: I never tested this solution so use it at your own risk. 

[This codeplex project](http://readunreadcolumn.codeplex.com/) seems to do what you are asking. Perhaps you could start there and implement a custom solution if no other answer is provided.

Comment: If its a dynamic value, you can use a calculated column to pull data from other columns. Whats your exact intention? Can you ellaborate the question?

Comment: Whilst this is subtly different to the question you asked yesterday, it is leading to the same solution. I am therefore merging the two questions.

Comment: @ Deepu Nair  How to give a record is read?

Answer (score 3):

You could edit the DispForm of the list item and in it have a delegatecontrol (or some other custom control) to count how many times the page has been loaded by unique user id's other than the authors id.

**Update**

Create a new user/web/delegate control and insert the following code:

```
var web = SPContext.Current.Site.OpenWeb();
var list = web.Lists["Name of the list"];
var itemId = Page.Request.QueryString["ID"];
var item = list.Items.Cast<SPListItem>().FirstOrDefault(i => i.ID.Equals(itemId));
var isRead = (bool)item["Internal name of the column"];
if(!isRead)
{
    item["Internal name of the column"] = true;
    item.Update();
}
```

This should pretty much do the job of updating the items column stating if it's read or not.

Comment: I have a column with false value . How do i change value when DispForm is display?

Comment: @niloo Please read my update.

Comment: thanks a lot . but how i can created a new user/web/delegate control?

Comment: @niloo You do this in Visual Studio. I take it you're not a developer, so I suggest you get a hold of one who can develop the control and insert it correctly for you.

Comment: how can i edit a DispForm.aspx in visual studio?

Comment: @niloo You can't. It's only possible in the SharePoint Designer as DispForm.aspx is unique for each list created. Thus you have to edit the DispForm.aspx in SharePoint Designer.

Comment: Please explain more about the  created a new user/web/delegate control!

Answer (score 0):

You can set the default value for the field in list....

Comment: i have a field with false value , i want set true when dispform is load.

Comment: Make it true by default...????

Comment: yes ,  i want set default value

Comment: Go to list settings>>> select your column>> click it>> u find default value...>> select ur value and click Ok... :)

Comment: thanks , but i want set default value when dispform is load .i don't set value when item is created

Comment: if .. u have.. value by default on creation.. u will have it the same on dispform also ???

Comment: I have a list with multiple columns.
This list may include multiple records. I want the value of a specific field to be true when a special record is read for the first time.(when dispform is load value change)

Comment: Thn... u can customize ur list in InfoPath designer.. and do set the default values as u need ...

Comment: Please explain more, how can i customize my list in InfoPath designer?

Comment: Goto you list... In the ribbon.. Check for Customize Form.. click it... It will open in InfoPath designer(If you have it installed in ur system)... In that Form, select the control for which you need to set the default value... then right click properties... u will find default value.. try it...

Comment: in InfoPath designer , i can set value for field when item is created. but i can set value when dispform is load.

Comment: You can set rules in InfoPath... matching your requirements...

Comment: Please explain more , can i set rule for dispform ?

Comment: When you customize ur list int InfoPath... It applies to all(edit,display and new)... Try it...

Answer (score 0):

There are several solutions:

1. You can open this form in SharePoint designer, add to this form Edit Content WebPart. To this web part you can add java script that finds your drop down box and set your value.
2. You can create your own [field](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/Freddy_Khalaf/creating-custom-fields-in-sharepoint/) in VS2010. In this field you can set your value.
3. You can create your own [template](http://pholpar.wordpress.com/2011/10/16/customizing-sharepoint-forms-via-creating-our-own-listfielditerator/) in VS2010 for this form. In this template you can use JS, remove ListFieldIterator and set your own markup, or use your own iterator.