# How to set field value on DispForm.aspx?

Tags: sharepoint-designer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can i realize a record of list has been read?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/25954/how-can-i-realize-a-record-of-list-has-been-read)

I have a list . I want set field value when dispform is load .

My question is how can I set the value with the field ?